# how disable default netbeans settings for phpunit

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

when i run phpUnit test in our project (Alt+F6) NetBeans always run it as:

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/usr/bin/phpunit" "--colors" "--log-junit" "/tmp/nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--configuration" "/storage/proj/t4/products/t42base/web/tests/phpunit.xml" "/home/maxgu/etc/netbeans-7.4/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=/storage/proj/t4/products/t42base/web/tests"
```

how i can disable this option:

```
"/home/maxgu/etc/netbeans-7.4/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=/storage/proj/t4/products/t42base/web/tests"
```

?

with this option phpunit ignore settings from XML config file:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Pages">
        <directory>../module/Pages/test/UnitTest</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Application">
        <directory>../module/Application/test/UnitTest</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: What about configuring Netbeans to use the XML?

Comment: @Sven how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom configuration for phpunit in project options
[image]

Comment: Netbeans run all test from folder in Config>Sources>Test Folder and ignore &gt;testsuites&lt from phpunit.xml